# how to use sed in a specific column of a tabular file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a tabular file `A.tsv` (separator=`\t`) :

```
20655|dkljdjj   66  lala
20644|kmkmoii   75  lolo
20477|kmlkooo   88  lili
```

And I want to remove all the things after the `|` ( `|` pipe include ) in the first column, in order to have that :

```
20655   66  lala
20644   75  lolo
20477   88  lili
```

I know how to do that with sed : `sed 's/|.*//' A.tsv > B.tsv` but it remove all after the pipe , not only the first column.

So do you know how to do that ? Maybe with a combination with awk ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace `.` (any character) by `[^\t]` (any character except tab) or `[^[:blank:]]` (any character excluding horizontal whitespace):

```
sed 's/|[^\t]*//' A.tsv > B.tsv

sed 's/|[^[:blank:]]*//' A.tsv > B.tsv
```

If you prefer awk:

```
awk '{sub(/\|.*/,"",$1)} 1' OFS='\t' A.tsv
```

Comment: Thanks, I will remember this regex next time !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use grouping with `sed`

```
sed -E 's/(\S+)\|\S+\s(.*$)/\1\2/' inputfile
```

**Output**

```
20655  66  lala
20644  75  lolo
20477  88  lili
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `\S/\s` and GNU or BSD sed for `-E`.